# airflow does not send emails when jobs are launched?

Tags: airflow

I set up dags as below. I launched this dag by

```
airflow backfill jobs -s 2017-05-01 -e 2017-06-07
```

I did not receive any emails although the jobs are successful.
Am I suppose to do anything else to receive the email?
Or I should run dag in a different way?

dag as below:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 5, 01),
    'end_date': datetime(2017, 6, 3),
    'email': ['Owner@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html?highlight=email) gives the option to send email only on retry and failure by default. To send email on success, you can add [EmailOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=email#airflow.operators.email_operator.EmailOperator) in your DAG at the end.